# Java object serializer which is based on field order

Tags: java, json, serialization, obfuscation

Does anyone know a reflection based Java object graph serializer, which stores the fields identified by field order instead name of the field? This is what I want to do:

1. load a JSON file with Jackson JSON deserializer
2. save it in binary format which doesn't contain the field names...
3. load the previously serialized object with the OBFUSCATED version of the application.

The serialized content won't be transferred to any other JVM. Excluding serialized POJOs from obfuscation is not an option for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Protostuff](http://www.protostuff.io/documentation/runtime-schema/) by default orders fields from top to bottom as defined in your pojo. You can additionally control the field number using annotations.

> Note that the order is not guaranteed on some (non-sun) vms (especially dalvik).
>
> Sun jdk6 or higher is recommended for guaranteed ordering.